# Why can't TRAMP assume current host for `sudo::`?

Tags: tramp

**Are there any technical reasons or use cases for why `sudo::` in TRAMP cannot use the rightmost host to the left of it, instead of localhost?**

When I do `/ssh:myname@my-remote-hostname.example.com|sudo::/tmp/file`, I would expect the `sudo::` to implicitly use `root@my-remote-hostname.example.com`.

More generally, when multiple SSH hops are chained together, such as in`/ssh:jumpbox.example.com|ssh:remote.example.com|sudo::/tmp/file`, I would expect the `sudo::` to always use the rightmost host to the left of the `sudo::`.

I expect this because **from a user interface and experience perspective**, to me this seems like the obviously more **intuitive** and most **convenient** behavior for it to do.

But this does not happen. Instead, `sudo::` seems to always implicitly use root @ the local host.

I understand that this is how it is. What I don't understand is why? Are there **technical reasons** for why implementing this would be difficult, or common **use cases** I am not imagining that would be broken if this was implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be happy to learn that in more recent tramp releases (first included in Emacs 27.1) the `::` case will work the way you want it to, such that `/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo::` will re-use `remotehost` rather than your own local hostname, so you won't end up with a bad proxy entry.

In addition, the likes of `/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:localhost:` are detected and flagged as user errors.

Of course, if you are liable to use a mixture of Emacs versions, you should continue to treat `::` as unsafe when multi-hopping in general, to avoid potential mishap.

-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs/16408592#comment94821206_16408592

Comment: So I think this answers my question implicitly: no, there are no technical issues or use cases preventing it, as evidence by the fact that it was recently done. Thanks!

Comment: And in case you cannot upgrade to the just released Emacs 27.1, you might use Tramp from GNU ELPA. That version has also solved the problem.